# Chrome extension or other tool for measuring bandwidth of my portable chrome on my laptop?

Tags: chrome, bandwidth

I have a worker who is working for me through portable chrome with proxy on his own laptop. The proxy have no option to check the bandwidth my worker use daily. I need some chrome extension or some windows simple tool where I can see on a daily basis how much megabytes my worker downloaded/uploaded with this portable chrome. I found some not useful tools which measure only some request like chrome dev tools and other similar but not what I need. Do you know such tool?